# Trying to use value in form submission to check against external API

Tags: forms, api, plugin-gravity-forms, plugin-ninja-forms

I'm trying to be as concise as possible. I'm building a form that takes a value ('address') which in turn would get posted to an external API. However, the real functionality comes with checking the 'address' to see if it is eligible to sign up for a program.

[image]

The first box shows what happens when user enters an address into the form field. But what I need is to access the value in the JSON file below. Someone suggested that I use webhooks - which I looked up the documentation for various plugins (Gravity Forms, Fluent Forms and so on). But something tells me that I need to write a custom function in order to use the data collected from the form and check it against the API.

What is the solution to this? Is it even possible?

Disclaimer: I haven't been developing websites for a while and have chatted with another developer but I still haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Can you explain more about how you're collecting the address? Are you using a form plugin? Is the form on your WordPress site or another site?

I've done things like this using Gravity Forms but the process is similar across plugins. Usually the form plugin has an hook you can use to execute a function, and you can use that function to check the form value against the API.

Comment: I'm planning to use a form plugin, I was suggested to use Gravity Forms but seems like all the plugins has something similar to webhooks. However, I am also going to be using a page builder (Bricks) and is aware that I'm going to have to write some custom code. But I was wondering if I would need any type of custom function in the functions.php since I'm using the page builder.